# Python function to return a new list containing the strings that are palindromes and have an even length

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Practice Question:

> Given a list of strings, write a Python function to return a new list containing the strings that are palindromes and have an even length.
>
> For example:
>
> Input: `["radar", "level", "python", "noon", "racecar"]`
> Output: `["noon", "racecar"]`
>
> Write a function called `even_length_palindromes` that takes a list of strings as input and returns a new list containing only the palindromic strings with an even length.

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    if(string==string[::-1]):
        return(string)
    return()    
def even_length_palindromes(string):
    return(sample for sample in string if len(is_palindrome(sample))%2==0) 

print(list(even_length_palindromes(["radar", "level", "python", "noon", "racecar"])))
```

the qutput generated was `['python', 'noon']` insted of `['noon']`

Comment: When the string isn't a palindrome, you return an empty tuple. The length of this is 0, which is even.

Comment: You should return True or False from `is_palindrome()`. Check the length of the string separately from this function.

Comment: `return` is not a function.  It is a keyword.  You are actually returning the literal value `()`, which is an empty tuple.

Comment: @Barmar so ```return(sample for sample in string if is_palindrome(sample) and len(sample)%2==0) ``` while returning true or false from is palindrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Return a boolean from `is_palindrome()`, as its name suggests. Then test for even length separately.

You also need to use a list comprehension in `even_length_palindromes()`, since the description says it should return a list, not a generator.

```
def is_palindrome(string):
    return string == string[::-1]

def even_length_palindromes(string_list):
    return [sample for sample in string_list if len(sample) % 2 == 0 and is_palindrome(sample)]
```